# GraphApi permissions - unable to read list values while it is possible to read columns info

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am able to query graphapi for columns, GET request:

> /v1.0/sites/{siteId}/lists/{listId}/columns

But when I try to get list values, also GET request, i get empty array

> /v1.0/sites/{siteId}/lists/{listId}/items

(also tried with appending ?expand=fields(select=fieldName), where fieldName was name listed by columns GET response)

result:

```
{
   "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('{siteId}')/lists('{listId}')/items",
   "value": []
}
```

When i try to create row using POST request i receive access denied. I am accessing api using rest requests from soapui, my app which i use has Sites.Selected API permission and the site which I am using was assigned permission by link:

> https://{domain}.sharepoint.com/sites/{siteName}/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx

According to documentation to receive columns and list items same permission are required i.e. Sites.Read.All
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-list-columns?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Any idea why I can list columns but cannot list items (receive empty array as a result)?

Comment: Do you know which role was assigned to your app? If you remember which rights have been granted? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs

Comment: Write/Contributor was granted, turned out FullControl is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that Right="FullControl" was required